# The named parameter 'X' isn't defined. - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've getting these errors on my terminal, while I still define and declare then in the correct format.

```
The named parameter 'localDataSource' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'localDataSource'.
3 positional arguments expected by 'NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl.new', but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.
```

This is my injector file `injection_container.dart`.

```
final sl = GetIt.instance; // service locator

Future<void> init() async {
  /* Features - Number Trivia */
  // Bloc
  sl.registerFactory(
    () => NumberTriviaBloc(
      concrete: sl(),
      random: sl(),
      inputConverter: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //Use cases
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetConcreteNumberTrivia(sl()));
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetRandomNumberTrivia(sl()));

  // Repository
  sl.registerLazySingleton<NumberTriviaRepository>(
    () => NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl(
      localDataSource: sl(),   // Error
      remoteDataSource: sl(),  // Error
      networkInfo: sl(),       // Error
    ),
  );
```

This is my repository implementation file `number_trivia_repository_impl.dart`.

```
typedef Future<NumberTrivia> _ConcreteOrRandomChooser();

class NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl implements NumberTriviaRepository {
  final NumberTriviaRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;
  final NumberTriviaLocalDataSource localDataSource;
  final NetworkInfo networkInfo;

  NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl(
    @required this.remoteDataSource,
    @required this.localDataSource,
    @required this.networkInfo,
    // {required networkInfo}
  );
```

What I have to do now for using the implementation parameters? As I already added them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate the class by using named parameters, when they are actually positional parameters.
Change the instantiation to this:

```dart
  // Repository
  sl.registerLazySingleton<NumberTriviaRepository>(
    () => NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl(
      sl(),
      sl(),
      sl(),
    ),
  );
```

or if you want to use named parameters, change the constructor to this:

```dart
  NumberTriviaRepositoryImpl({
    required this.remoteDataSource,
    required this.localDataSource,
    required this.networkInfo,
  });
```

Note the `{}` which denotes that it is named arguments.